# How to check if all the values of a key inside an object array is 0?

Tags: javascript

I have below object inside an array

```
[
    {
        "event":"a",
        "count":0
    },
    {
        "event":"b",
        "count":0
    },
    {
        "event":"c",
        "count":0
    }
]
```

I need to check if all values of count is zero.

I have tried below code

```
Object.values(alarmTypeCount).every(count => count === 0)
```

it returns false every time

Answer (score 5):

You need a destructuring of the object to get the wanted property.

```js
var alarmTypeCount = [{ event: "a", count: 0 }, { event: "b", count: 0 }, { event: "c", count: 0 }],
    allCountsZero = Object.values(alarmTypeCount).every(({ count }) => count === 0);

console.log(allCountsZero);
```

Or take the object with a property.

```js
var alarmTypeCount = [{ event: "a", count: 0 }, { event: "b", count: 0 }, { event: "c", count: 0 }],
    allCountsZero = Object.values(alarmTypeCount).every(o => o.count === 0);

console.log(allCountsZero);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to destructure your argument of 'every' function

```
Object.values(alarmTypeCount).every(({ count }) => count === 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `Object.values()` on an array is redundant as it will simply just give you an array of the elements (objects in your case) within your array, which is what your array is anyway. `count` in your example represents a given object in your array. You need to access the object `count` property like so:

```
alarmTypeCount.every(obj => obj.count === 0)
```

Or, you can do it through destructuring assignment:

```
alarmTypeCount.every(({count}) => count === 0)
```

See example below:

```js
let alarmTypeCount = [{"event":"a", "count":0}, {"event":"b", "count":0}, {"event":"c", "count":0}];

console.log(alarmTypeCount.every(obj => obj.count === 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several options using `Array.prototype` methods, here's a summary, inlcuding some of the options mentioned here by others:

Using [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
const isAllZeros = alarmTypeCount.every(a => a.count === 0)
```

Using [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
const isAllZeros = !alarmTypeCount.some(a => a.count !== 0)
```

Using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
const isAllZeros = !alarmTypeCount.find(a => a.count !== 0)
```

Using [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```
const isAllZeros = alarmTypeCount.findIndex(a => a.count !== 0) === -1
```

Using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const isAllZeros = alarmTypeCount.filter(a => a.count !== 0).length === 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the `filter` method

```js
let array = [
    {
        "event":"a",
        "count":0
    },
    {
        "event":"b",
        "count":0
    },
    {
        "event":"c",
        "count":0
    }
]

let newArray = array.filter((obj)=>{
  return obj.count > 0;
});

if(newArray.length == 0){
  console.log("All the elements are zero");
}else{
  console.log(newArray.length + " elements are non zero");
}
```